# Am I showing relations correctly using subsets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is:

Let $S = \left\{a,b,c\right\}$. Recall that a relation on $S$ is a subset of $S\times S$. Give
an example of a relation $R$ on $S$ that is reflexive and:

a. Symmetric but not anti-symmetric.

b. Anti-symmetric but not symmetric.

c. Neither symmetric nor anti-symmetric.

d. Both symmetric and anti-symmetric.

Here are my answers:

$S = \left\{a,b,c\right\}$

a. Reflexive, symmetric, not anti-symmetric

$~~~~R = \left\{(a,a),(b,b),(b,c),(c,b),(c,c)\right\}$

b. Reflexive, Anti-symmetric, not symmetric

$~~~~R = \left\{(a,a),(b,a),(b,b),(c,c)\right\}$

c. Reflexive, not symmetric, not anti-symmetric

$~~~~R = \left\{(a,a),(b,a),(a,b),(b,c),(b,b),(c,c)\right\}$

d. Reflexive, symmetric and antisymmetric

$~~~~R = \left\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)\right\}$

If you notice any errors, I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answers you gave are correct.

In each case reflexivity comes from the presence of the pairs $(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)$.

Symmetry means whenever the pair $(a,b)$ occurs, $(b,a)$ occurs.

Antisymmetry means no pairs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ for distinct $a,b$.